# Matlab - use a previously calculated value to calculate a new value for a specific number of iterations

Tags: matlab

In simplest terms, I have a function and I want to start with f(1) and solve the equation (let's say f(1)=54.)  Then take that value and use it to calculate the next value (f(54)=something), and do that 50 times.  I am sure I need to use a loop to accomplish this, but I don't know how to execute it.

In more complex terms, I am trying to solve a load flow problem using Gauss-Seidel.  I can calculate it by hand and the program really just needs to be able to take the previous calculation and make it the new variable over and over again.  I have looked for a loop that clearly states how to accomplish this, but much of what I find doesn't have enough ELI5 comments for me to apply that code to what I'm doing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mean they even give a matlab function in wiki page and still : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Program_to_solve_arbitrary_no._of_equations_using_Matlab

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 1 ; % counter
nloops = 50 % times to loop
while count < nloops
  if count ==1
     fresult = f(count); % first loop use count = 1 value as input
  else 
    fresult = f(fresult); % next loops use fresult as input
  end
count = count + 1;
end
```

The above code will loop nloop times. In the first loop will store f result in fresult variable, and in the next iterations will use the value of fresult as a input of f!

I hope this helps you.